# group values in 1-50, 51-100,101-150 etc in crystalreport

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I have list of values(selected from DB) that start from 1 but the end range is unknown,and i want to group this values in crystal report in such a way that
values between 1 to 50 then 51 to 100 then 101 to 150 etc up to the maximum value.
how should i group??

```
    eg: The selected values of the column rate are
         1,1.6,2,56,71.1,61.9,109,118 etc.
        i want to group like
       rate range(1-50)
            1
            1.6
            2
          -------------------------------
         rate range(51-100)
            56
           71.1
           61.9
         --------------------
       rate range(101-150)
        109
        118
    etc.
    but i don't know the exact max value of the list
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula similar to this logic, and group the report on that formula:

```
NumberVar YourValue := 300 ;
NumberVar FromValue := 50*Floor(YourValue/50) ;
NumberVar ToValue := FromValue + 50 ;
ToText(FromValue,0,"") & "-" & ToText(ToValue,0,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create following formula and group the report on that formula.

```
Floor(({yourTable.Value}-1)/50)+1
```

It returns the group number. Examples:

- for the value `23` it returns `1`
- for the value `150.99` it returns `3`
- for the value `543` it returns `11`.

Use following formula as group title:

```
"rate range(" & CStr({@GroupNumber}*50-49, "#") & "-" & CStr({@GroupNumber}*50, "#") & ")"
```